# Show the results of linked list operations in sequence

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm working on a basic linked list programs. In this program I can insert elements at the beginning, at the middle (after one specific element) of the list and at the end. I also can delete a specific element or delete an element from the end of the list. I have all these four methods in the code.

Now I was trying in the main method to perform this operations in sequence:

1. insert at the beginning
2. insert at the middle
3. delete a specific element
4. delete an element from the list.

First I want to add 10 elements at the beginning of the list `{50, 70, 80, 100, 77, 200, 44, 70, 6, 0}`. Then I want to add 10 elements at the middle `{ 5, 20, 10 ,30 ,7 , 8, 2, 104, 1, 22}` after the element `200`. Then I want to add 10 elements at the end `{40, 30, 20, 1, 7, 76, 4 , 0, 80, 2}`. Then I want to delete a specific element `76` and then delete two elements at the end of the list.

So, I want the final list as `{0, 6, 70, 44, 200, 22, 1, 104, 2, 8, 7, 30, 10, 20, 5, 77, 100, 80, 70, 50, 40, 30, 20, 1, 7, 4, 0}`.

I don't know if it's  a good way. Do you think the code in the main method is OK, the `for` parts particularly?

Main method:

```
int main()
{
    printf("hi");
    int i=0;
    int listsize=10;
    int arrBegining[] = {50,70, 80, 100, 77, 200, 44, 70, 6, 0};
    int arrMiddle[] = {5, 20, 10, 30, 7, 8, 2, 104, 1, 22};
    int arrEnd[] = {40, 30, 20, 1, 7, 76, 4 , 0, 80, 2};

    for(i=0;i<listsize;i++){
            insert_at_begning(arrBegining[i]);
        }

    for(i=0;i<listsize;i++){
        insert_at_middle(arrMiddle[i], 200);
    }
    for(i=0;i<listsize;i++){
        insert_at_end(arrEnd[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<listsize;i++){
        delete_from_middle(76);
    }

    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        delete_from_end();
    }
 }
```

List operations:

```
void insert_at_begning(int value)
{
    var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    var->data=value;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=var;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        var->next=head;
        head=var;
    }
}

void insert_at_middle(int value, int loc)
{
    struct node *var2,*temp;
    var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    var->data=value;
    temp=head;

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=var;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp->data!=loc)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        var2=temp->next;
        temp->next=var;
        var->next=var2;
    }
}

int delete_from_middle(int value)
{
    struct node *temp,*var;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data == value)
        {
            if(temp==head)
            {
                head=temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                var->next=temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var=temp;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    printf("data deleted from list is %d",value);
}

int delete_from_end()
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=head;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        var=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(temp ==head)
    {
        head=temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("data deleted from list is %d",temp->data);
    var->next=NULL;
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Typo in method name?**

`insert_at_begning` looks like it should be called `insert_at_beginning`?

**insert_at_middle**

The method name doesn't seem to match what it actually does.  It looks more like it's `insert_after`.

It also looks like it has a memory leak, what happens if you attempt to insert after a value that isn't currently in the list?

**var**

`var` is not a good name for a variable, it is totally nondescript. It is even worse when it is declared at a global/file scope where it's declaration isn't even visible.  You appear to be using a global variable `var` in your insert methods, however have a local `var` in your `delete_from_middle` method.  This is confusing.  Variable should be named after what they represent from a logical perspective.  You should also try to avoid using the same name for variables in nested scopes.

**main**

Your main looks mostly ok as a test harness, however it's rather inefficient.  Since your list doesn't maintain a tail pointer, inserting at the end is much slower than inserting at the beginning.  Similarly, inserting in the middle is relatively slow.  It would be more efficient to insert everything from the end to the front, rather than from the front to the end.

I'd also personally store the arrays to be inserted in the order that I wanted them to be in the list (not backwards), then iterate through them in reverse order.  I know this has the same effect, but when I look at the code I would then be able to see the list rather than having to mentally flip the arrays.